# Node.js: close one side of a tee stream

Tags: node.js

I have an [S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) object that I am using to store data in. Periodically I have updates to the blob-stored blob. In an effort to keep memory usage low, I open a stream and write it back, while applying the updates.

My problem is that some of the updates will result in the blob getting bigger, and I have to specify the `content-length` at the time of the write operation. To determine this, I need the header from the initial blob. So I [teed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) the stream, read the header off the first side of the tee, and then did the transform on the second half of the stream:

```js
let doc = await db.send(new GetObjectCommand({Bucket: 'things', Key: key}));
let stms = Readable.toWeb(doc.Body).tee();

// Calculate the length of the destination stream
let newlength = await stms[0]
    .pipeThrough(CalcStreamLength(updates))
    .getReader()
    .read()
    ;
newlength = newlength.value;
//stm[0].close(); // THIS DOES BAD THINGS

// Transform the stream and write to destination
stms[1] = stms[1].pipeThrough(CalcNewDataset(fields, updates));
stms[1] = Readable.fromWeb(stms[1]);
await context.send(new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'things',
    Key: key,
    Body: stms[1],
    ContentLength: newlength,
}));
```

This leads to major memory consumption (the exact thing I am trying to avoid) as the whole first stream gets buffered into memory.

> If only one branch is consumed, then the entire body will be enqueued in memory.
>
> [ReadableStream: tee method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/tee)

Is there an obvious way around this that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my other answer is valid, and still has some value to me, the solution to this problem is actually to use an upload mechanism that does not require me to know how big the stream is: MultiUpload.

To do this, the simplest implementation appears to be to use *[@aws-sdk/lib-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/lib-storage)*.

This is specifically used when you don't know what the total length will be:

> This abstraction enables uploading large files or streams of unknown size

This allows me to dispose of the `tee` all together.

```js
    let key = `company/${req.key}`;
    let rtn = null;
    stm = stm
        .pipeThrough(CalcNewDataset(updates))
        ;
    stm = Readable.fromWeb(stm);
    stm = stm
        .pipe(zlib.createBrotliCompress({}))
        ;
    let upload = new Upload({
        client: getS3Client(),
        params: {
            Bucket: 'facts',
            Key: key,
            //Metadata: meta, // This doesn't do anything
            Body: stms[1],
        },
    });

    upload.on('httpUploadProgress',(e)=>{
        console.log(`${e.Key}: ${e.part}`);
    });
    rtn = await upload.done();
```

This loses the ability to create a progress bar, since I can't tell how long the total is. An advantage is that I am also able to introduce compression (`createBrotliCompress`), and (not needing the `tee`) can stop switching between a WebStream and a Node.js Stream.

The biggest issue I have seen is that you lose the metadata portion.

Answer (score 0):

This ended with a bit of [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ... thank you for listening to my problem description.

If the problem is that the first stream ends up buffering the data as the second stream is consumed, I really need to drain the first stream at the same speed I drain the second stream.

```js
let doc = await db.send(new GetObjectCommand({Bucket: 'things', Key: key}));
let stms = Readable.toWeb(doc.Body).tee();

// calculate the length of the destination stream
let reader = stms[0]
    .pipeThrough(CalcStreamLength(updates))
    .getReader()
    ;
let newlength = await reader.read();
newlength = newlength.value;
//stm[0].close(); // THIS DOES BAD THINGS

// now create a transform that keeps tracks of how many bytes
// ahead the stream is. This is initialized off the number of
// bytes the header read would have already done. It doesn't
// have to be exact ... just close
let aheadBytes = (4 + updates[0].length) * 4;
let DrainStream = new TransformStream({
  async transform(chunk, controller) {
    // no matter what, we are going to want to pass this on
    controller.enqueue(chunk);
    // as bytes are read off the second stream, we can subtract that
    // from the "ahead" distance of the first stream
    aheadBytes -= chunk.length * chunk.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    // if the first stream falls behind again, have it catch up
    // by having it read a chunk out of its buffer. Once its
    // caught up, continue on.
    for(let buffer = await reader.read(); aheadBytes < 0 && !buffer.done; buffer = await reader.read()){
      aheadBytes += buffer.value.length * buffer.value.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    }
  }
});

// Transform the stream and write to destination
stms[1] = stms[1]
  // add that draining routine to the transform set of the second stream
  .pipeThrough(DrainStream)
  .pipeThrough(CalcNewDataset(updates))
  ;

/***** CONTINUE ON AS BEFORE ******/
```

Doing this will drain the unused stream at roughly the same pace as the main stream. This will prevent it buffering the entirety of the data while it is unused.